# Trying to implement axios with post in body with headers inside

Tags: wordpress, jwt, axios, nativescript, vue-native

I'm implementing jwt with wordpress in vueNative App. When i am call the api i am getting the provisional headers are show warning. I am getting the 403 error also .below is my code that i wrote.

```
 axios.post('https://ishopee.in/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',null,{
                    headers: {
                    'username': 'nayanjariwala123456789@gmail.com',
                    'password': 'Baby_0123'
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("---->SuccessFully Login".res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('--->'+err); 
                })
```

And This is the request i made from my vue native app

```
header
Request URL: https://ishopee.in/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Allow: POST
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,43,46", h3-22=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2019 08:33:00 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Link: <https://ishopee.in/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
null: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Pragma: no-cache
Server: LiteSpeed
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dd9ecfdbdae48539a6bd1d1847d68c1d; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Android-Received-Millis: 1571214780555
X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 403
X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1571214777449
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.28
X-Robots-Tag: noindex

Request Header
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
password: Baby_0123
username: nayanjariwala123456789@gmail.com
```

Comment: Did you verify the API response for the credentials with REST client?

Comment: yes its working in postman

Comment: Are you sure you had to pass the information on header? Are you doing the same from POSTMAN? Looks like your API seems to accept username and password on JSON body not headers.

Answer (score 0):

JSON body Seems working i made the below request and now it works

```
axios.post('https://ishopee.in/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',
                    {
                        'username': 'nayanjariwala123456789@gmail.com',
                        'password': 'Baby_123'
                    }
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("--->SuccessFully Login".res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('--->'+err); 
                })
```